# Will crypto.getRandomValues return negative values?

Tags: javascript

Below is code from https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

```
var a = new Uint32Array(1);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(a);
return a[0] & 2147483647;
```

As far as I can imagine, `a positive value & 2147483647` will always be itself. If it's necessary, can I deduce that the `crypto.getRandomValues` will return negative values? I cannot find that from MDN.

Answer (score 2):

The [Web Cryptography API draft](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcrypto-api/raw-file/tip/spec/Overview.html#Crypto-method-getRandomValues) states (emphasis mine):

> 1. If array is not of an integer type (i.e., `Int8Array`, `Uint8Array`, `Int16Array`, `Uint16Array`, `Int32Array`, or
>      `Uint32Array`), throw a TypeMismatchError and terminate the algorithm.
> 2. If the byteLength of array is greater than 65536, throw a QuotaExceededError and terminate the algorithm.
> 3. Overwrite all elements of array with cryptographically random values **of the appropriate type**.

In other words: if you pass an `Int*` array as argument, you can expect negative values. If you don't want those, use `Uint*` (which you're already doing, so you can expect `a[0]` to be positive).

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I figure it out that, the `UInt32` is a byte "longer" than `2147483647`. It seems positive but "practically" negative.